# After mvn install I try to run main, but I get a NoClassDefFoundError in ConfigurationException

Tags: java, exception, maven-2, program-entry-point, apache-commons-config

I created a maven project and I have written for weeks an application and want to run it in the end... But I can't.

I get the following stacktrace when executing my .jar:

```
C:\Users\MyUser\.m2\repository\com\myCompany\MyApp\
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT> java -Dconfigfile=config.xml -jar MyApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/configuration/ConfigurationException
        at com.mycompany.connector.DBConnector.reloadDBSettings(DBConnector.java:23)
        at com.mycompany.connector.DBConnector.<clinit>(DBConnector.java:16)
        at com.mycompany.connector.DBConnectorFactory.createDBConnector(DBConnectorFactory.java:17)
        at com.mycompany.service.MyAppService.<clinit>(MyAppService.java:38)
        at com.mycompany.main.MyAppMain.init(MyAppMain.java:13)
        at com.mycompany.main.MyAppMain.main(MyAppMain.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more
```

org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException is imported to the class and I set up Maven to use it as dependency. What am I doing wrong?

BTW: this is my reloadDBSettings Method:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration;

public final class ConfigurationHandler {

    private static XMLConfiguration config;
/**
     * to reload Configuration-File if necessary
     */
    public static void reloadConfig() throws FileNotFoundException {
            try {
                config = new XMLConfiguration(System.getProperty("configfile"));
            } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Es wurde keine Konfiguration geladen - Überprüfen Sie die Systemvariable 'configfile'(" + e.getMessage() + ")");
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClassNotFoundException` means JVM cannot find the class in your classpath. This is different from `NoClassDefFoundError` which means the classes use by that class are not found (not the class itself).

There are two ways to solve this problem:

1. add all the dependent jar files to a folder, add that to JVM classpath and run your main class using:

   `java -cp .\dependency\*;MyApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.jar com.myCompany.MyApp.Main`

   and in order to get all the dependencies into a folder you can use maven dependencies plugin [`maven-dependency-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/)
2. use maven assembly plugin [`maven-assembly-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/). This plugin will bundle all the dependent jar files in to a signle jar file so you can execute it the same way you do. However, sometime this method does not work especially for a larger application that use a lot of libraries. The jars may conflict each other so you may need to resolve the dependencies yourself or use [Tattletale](http://www.jboss.org/tattletale) maven plugin to solve it for you.

Note: Tattletale is also good to solve conflict in the first case.

Answer (score 2):

A `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` means that you don't have the `org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException` in your `$CLASSPATH` variable in your shell, and running a `java` command on the command-line is not the same as running/compiling through Maven.

Comment: can I set it up in POM? Or what do I need to do. Where can I find the class after mvn install?

Answer (score 2):

Use [exec:java](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html). Maven will include all necessary classes on the classpath.

Add configuration (under `<plugins>` in your pom.xml):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
   <configuration>
      <arguments>
        <argument>-Dconfigfile=config.xml</argument>
      </arguments>
      <mainClass>com.tele2.main.MyAppMain</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Run via `mvn exec:java`